# Adjust Dialog Width jQuery Mobile to non-Ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to open a popup window to a custom size.  Using suggestions from jQuery mobile docs I can get the custom size to work when I load the page with ajax (in the same .html document).  When I have a separate .html document, it doesn't load the custom width I specify.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" > 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .ui-dialog .ui-header, 
        .ui-dialog .ui-content, 
        .ui-dialog .ui-footer { 
            max-width: 800px; 
            margin: 10% auto 15px auto; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="popup">
<div data-role="content">
    <a data-role="button" href="#" data-rel="back">back</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code.  If I link to it within the same file, and just use

```
<a href="#popup" data-rel="dialog">popup</a>
```

It works fine.  You can see the css rules that jQuery Mobile says to add if you want to change the width ([jQuery Mobile Dialog docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html)).

Comment: I answered my own question. I found that with the ajax loading, when the page is fetched it only gets the content from the target page. If I want to provide some custom CSS to be applied to the target page, I need to have it on the parent page (or the page that calls the popup).  I will mark this answered as soon as my 8 hours are up.

Comment: either on the parent page or within the div role=page (including JS code!). or, you could disable the ajaxLoading and not let jqm dynamically load the pages, but rather browser-load in the "classic" way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.  I found that with the ajax loading, when the page is fetched it only gets the  content from the target page.  If I want to provide some custom CSS to be applied to the target page, I need to have it on the parent page (or the page that is calling the popup).